# Clustering list for hclust function

Tags: r, hclust

Using `plot(hclust(dist(x)))` method, I was able to draw a cluster tree map. It works. Yet I would like to get a list of all clusters, not a tree diagram, because I have huge amount of data (like 150K nodes) and the plot gets messy.

In other words, lets say if `a b c` is a cluster and if `d e f g` is a cluster then I would like to get something like this:

```
1 a,b,c
2 d,e,f,g
```

Please note that this is not exactly what I want to get as an "output". It is just an example. I just would like to be able to get a list of clusters instead of a tree plot  It could be vector, matrix or just simple numbers that show which groups elements belong to.

How is this possible?

Comment: This may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378113/match-and-add-the-cluster-number-to-the-original-data/28384937#28384937

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I will use the dataset available in R to demonstrate how to cut a tree into desired number of pieces. Result is a table.

Construct a hclust object.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
#plot(hc)
```

You can now cut the tree into as many branches as you want. For my next trick, I will split the tree into two groups. You set the number of cuts with the `k` parameter. See `?cutree` and the use of paramter `h` which may be more useful to you (see `cutree(hc, k = 2) == cutree(hc, h = 110)`).

```
cutree(hc, k = 2)
       Alabama         Alaska        Arizona       Arkansas     California 
             1              1              1              2              1 
      Colorado    Connecticut       Delaware        Florida        Georgia 
             2              2              1              1              2 
        Hawaii          Idaho       Illinois        Indiana           Iowa 
             2              2              1              2              2 
        Kansas       Kentucky      Louisiana          Maine       Maryland 
             2              2              1              2              1 
 Massachusetts       Michigan      Minnesota    Mississippi       Missouri 
             2              1              2              1              2 
       Montana       Nebraska         Nevada  New Hampshire     New Jersey 
             2              2              1              2              2 
    New Mexico       New York North Carolina   North Dakota           Ohio 
             1              1              1              2              2 
      Oklahoma         Oregon   Pennsylvania   Rhode Island South Carolina 
             2              2              2              2              1 
  South Dakota      Tennessee          Texas           Utah        Vermont 
             2              2              2              2              2 
      Virginia     Washington  West Virginia      Wisconsin        Wyoming 
             2              2              2              2              2
```

Comment: excellent! thank you. This makes me think how one can possibly approximate a good value for parameter "k" so that the number of clusters in the data is what it should be instead of what I want it to be?  In other words, what if if I dont know how many cuts I need to make because I dont know how many clusters there are in the data. That is indeed what I am trying to find out that is to say the number of clusters and the elements within each cluster. Sorry if I was not clear earlier.

Comment: @dave, is it possible for you to know at which height you want to cut the tree? If yes, use the parameter `h` (see `?cutree`). The function will return the appropriate number of groups (and allegiance of leaves).

Comment: I see, maybe this is what I can do, hclust objects have components such as merge matrix, heights etc. lets say if a is a hclust  object, we can access possible heights using a$height.So  maybe selecting the max height from that matrix, I can possibly find out the number of possible clusters. That is what I was able to find thru my reading.

Answer (score 19):

lets say,

```
y<-dist(x)
clust<-hclust(y)
groups<-cutree(clust, k=3)
x<-cbind(x,groups)
```

now you will get for each record, the cluster group. 
You can subset the dataset as well:

```
x1<- subset(x, groups==1)
x2<- subset(x, groups==2)
x3<- subset(x, groups==3)
```