# Tagging adjacent points in a matrix

Tags: r, algorithm

I have an 8x8 matrix:

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Code to create it:

```
examplemat <- matrix(c(1, 1, rep(0, 6), 1, rep(0, 9), 1, 1, rep(0, 17), 1, rep(0, 7), 1, rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0, 11), 1), 8, 8, byrow=T)
```

The ones have been extracted as coordinates:

```
onecoords <- which(examplemat == 1, arr.ind=T)

      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   2   1
 [3,]   1   2
 [4,]   3   3
 [5,]   3   4
 [6,]   7   4
 [7,]   5   6
 [8,]   6   6
 [9,]   8   8
```

I need a simple, vectorized approach to clustering the ones into groups of adjacent coordinates. (For the purposes of this task, I would like 4-way up/down/left/right adjacency, but you may also want the option of 8-way adjacency including the diagonals.)

In the example, we would end up with 5 clusters of cells:

```
      row col clus
 [1,]   1   1    A
 [2,]   2   1    A
 [3,]   1   2    A
 [4,]   3   3    B
 [5,]   3   4    B
 [6,]   7   4    C
 [7,]   5   6    D
 [8,]   6   6    D
 [9,]   8   8    E
```

The 4-way adjacency check is pretty simple: `sum(abs(onecoords[1,] - onecoords[2,])) == 1` But I'm struggling to work out how to vectorize this efficiently.

Comment: You might find something [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518133/clustering-list-for-hclust-function) useful and, hopefully, general enough; e.g. here `cbind(onecoords, clus = cutree(hclust(dist(onecoords, "maximum")), h = 1))`

Comment: I agree that some use of `dist` or a more general Mahalanobis distance function will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*With thanks to alexis_laz and Carl Witthoft for very helpful comments that enable me to answer this myself.*

**Four-way adjacency**

To obtain clusters based on 4-way adjacency, use hierarchical clustering with single linkage on Manhattan distance:

```
cbind(onecoords, clus = cutree(hclust(dist(onecoords, "manhattan"), "single"), h = 1))
      row col clus
 [1,]   1   1    1
 [2,]   2   1    1
 [3,]   1   2    1
 [4,]   3   3    2
 [5,]   3   4    2
 [6,]   7   4    3
 [7,]   5   6    4
 [8,]   6   6    4
 [9,]   8   8    5
```

**Eight-way adjacency**

To obtain clusters based on 8-way adjacency (including diagonals), use hierarchical clustering with single linkage on maximum distance:

```
cbind(onecoords, clus = cutree(hclust(dist(onecoords, "maximum"), "single"), h = 1))
```

**Difference between Manhattan and maximum distances**

In the example case, these both give the same results, but if you remove the first row, for example, you will see that Manhattan distance produces 6 clusters, while maximum distance produces 5 clusters.

```
cbind(onecoords[2:9,], clus = cutree(hclust(dist(onecoords[2:9,], "manhattan"), "single"), h = 1))
     row col clus
[1,]   2   1    1
[2,]   1   2    2
[3,]   3   3    3
[4,]   3   4    3
[5,]   7   4    4
[6,]   5   6    5
[7,]   6   6    5
[8,]   8   8    6
cbind(onecoords[2:9,], clus = cutree(hclust(dist(onecoords[2:9,], "maximum"), "single"), h = 1))
     row col clus
[1,]   2   1    1
[2,]   1   2    1
[3,]   3   3    2
[4,]   3   4    2
[5,]   7   4    3
[6,]   5   6    4
[7,]   6   6    4
[8,]   8   8    5
```