# how to get the list of genes in each cluster of a heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I have used the following code to make this heatmap for my large dataset. Now I want to get the name of rows (name of the genes) for the second cluster (red on the left and green on the right).
First I tried to follow the instructions on [this page](https://www.biostars.org/p/287512/) to separate clusters but due to the complexity of the dendrogram on the y-axis, the solutions were not practical for me.
Then I tried to make clusters before making the heatmap hoping to get the same result. the codes on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687891/r-how-do-i-display-clustered-matrix-heatmap-similar-color-patterns-are-grouped) did not generate the same heatmap.

is there any possible way that I could get the list of genes for the desired regions of the heatmap?

```
library(RColorBrewer)
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "black", "green"))(n = 100)

heatmap.2(as.matrix(sd_pol),
          col=my_palette, 
          density.info="none",
          trace="none",
          symm=F,symkey=F,symbreaks=F, scale="none",
          labRow=NA,
          main="test_heatmap",
          margins = c(8, 8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gplots/versions/3.0.4/topics/heatmap.2), heatmap.2 uses the function [`hclust`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/hclust) for clustering, so an approach for what you want to achieve would be to create the clustering object and then apply [`cutree`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dendextend/versions/1.7.0/topics/cutree) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518133/clustering-list-for-hclust-function).

However, you will have to tune the parameters h or k to get the results you want:

```
require(graphics)
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests))
cutree(hc,k = 2)
```

Output:

```
  Alabama         Alaska        Arizona       Arkansas     California       Colorado    Connecticut 
         1              1              1              2              1              2              2 
  Delaware        Florida        Georgia         Hawaii          Idaho       Illinois        Indiana 
         1              1              2              2              2              1              2 
      Iowa         Kansas       Kentucky      Louisiana          Maine       Maryland  Massachusetts 
         2              2              2              1              2              1              2 
...
```